# pressing the enter key on ok button of message box causes a repetitive message box

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an application developed using mvvm framework.
I have a textbox with validation to enter only characters otherwise display a message box.
once the message box with ok button is displayed, user clicks on enter key when the focus is on ok button of message box. on enter click message box pops up repeatedly. once the enter key is pressed the message box should not popup again.
How to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you please show the code?

Answer (score 0):

are you clearing the offensive text out of the text box? or is it coming back after the ok to see the offending text and infinitely respond before it can be manually cleared? can you explain more about the problem if this isnt a fix?

Comment: is that to say my hypothesis was correct? do you have it working?